# Set up a subsection for Google Analtyics

Tags: google-analytics

I have a client (on a shared enterprise site). He wants to share Google Analtyics data with an external marketing firm. I have a manager who while initially against this, has agreed to share information for *only parts of the site*. Luckily, the data to be shared falls under one path. That is, the external marketing firm should only see everything falling under `http://domain.com/section_to_share/` -- nothing outside of that scope.

How should I set up an external to only have access to that part of the data (`/section_to_share/*`)? How can I ensure management that they can only see `/section_to_share/` and nothing else? I'm navigating choppy waters.

### Update:

So I set up the Porfile and Filter based on suggestions. My current problem is that it doesn't seem to be reading any data.

[image]

So I'm doing something wrong. I just don't know where. I've set up the filter as follows.

[image]

Is there additional step(s) that I have overlooked?

Answer (score 1):

Create a new profile, go to the admin section, goto "Filters", set up a predefined filter to "Include Traffic from subdirectory equals"  and enter the path to the subdirectory in the text field. Then add the marketing company with read only access to the new profile.

Comment: Should I see data right away or does this filter/profile begin collecting data at the point it was created?